# How to convert raw github file data to JSON

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert github raw data to JSON but unfortunately I am not able to do that.
I am using reactJs
My Code:

```
fetch("https://api.github.com/repos/graphql-compose/graphql-compose-examples/contents/examples/northwind/data/csv/employees.csv")
          .then((res) => {
            if (res.ok) {
              return res.content; // need to convert this content to json
            } else {
              throw new Error("Something went wrong");
            }
          })
          .then((data) => console.log(data))
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
          });
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with [reactjs].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `json()` on the response. See "basic fetch request" example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

The `content` property contains a base64 encoded value but it also contains line breaks which have to be removed before you're able to convert using `atob`. Afterwards, you get CSV lines:

```
fetch("https://api.github.com/repos/graphql-compose/graphql-compose-examples/contents/examples/northwind/data/csv/employees.csv")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => console.log(atob(data.content.replace('\n', ''))))
```

Output:

```
employeeID,lastName,firstName,title,titleOfCourtesy,birthDate,hireDate,address,city,region,postalCode,country,homePhone,extension,photo,notes,reportsTo,photoPath
1,Davolio,Nancy,Sales Representative,Ms.,1948-12-08 00:00:00.000,1992-05-01 00:00:00.000,507 20th Ave. E. Apt. 2A,Seattle,WA,98122,USA,(206) 555-9857,5467,0x151C2F00020000000D000E0014002100FFFFFFFF4269746D617020496D616765005061696E742E506963747572650001050000020000000700000050427275736800000000000000000020540000424D20540000000000007600000028000000C0000000DF0000000100040000000000A0530000CE0E0000D80E0000000000,Education includes a BA in psychology from Colorado State University in 1970.  She also completed The Art of the Cold Call.  Nancy is a member of Toastmasters International.,2,http://accweb/emmployees/davolio.bmp
...
```

Comment: it is returning data in base64

Comment: I guess you forgot to chain it. `json()` returns another promise.
I just executed this in my browser developer console and got perfectly good looking JSON: `fetch("https://api.github.com/repos/graphql-compose/graphql-compose-examples/contents/examples/northwind/data/csv/employees.csv").then(res => res.json()).then(data => console.log(data))`

Comment: in that json data I want to convert that content property data to json

Comment: check data.content

Comment: Ok, there are line breaks in there `\n`, if you remove them you can use `atob` to convert the content. It's actually CSV, I hope you can take it from here!

`fetch("https://api.github.com/repos/graphql-compose/graphql-compose-examples/contents/examples/northwind/data/csv/employees.csv").then(res => res.json()).then(data => console.log(atob(data.content.replace('\n', ''))))`

Comment: I have amended my post to reflect this and appreciate if you accept it as an answer.

Comment: yes! now it's working as expected thanks